# how to draw dashed circle using Maker.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

wants to draw a dashed circle using Maker.js for canvas drawing in React app. Is there any possibility to draw it?

Comment: I don't see any options for setting the line style to dashed in the documentation. One option would be to draw it dashed yourself by calculating each of the needed arcs.